# can't group by with a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I'm doing cross validation (five fold). Then I want to calculate the mean value for each group in a given data set I used for that cv. Please note that I *need* to use the following functions.

```
data(mpg)
library(modelr)

cv  <- crossv_kfold(mpg, k = 5)

models1  <- map(cv$train, ~lm(hwy ~ displ, data = .))

get_pred  <- function(model, test_data){
  data  <- as.data.frame(test_data)
  pred  <- add_predictions(data, model)
  return(pred)
}

pred1  <- map2_df(models1, cv$test, get_pred, .id = "Run")

MSE1  <- pred1 %>% group_by(Run) %>% 
  summarise(MSE = mean( (hwy - pred)^2))
MSE1
```

My problem lies with the output of 'summarise'. The function should be applied to each group. The result should look something like this:

```
## # A tibble: 5 x 2
##     Run       MSE
##   <chr>     <dbl>
## 1     1 27.889532
## 2     2  8.673054
## 3     3 17.033056
## 4     4 12.552037
## 5     5  9.138741
```

Unfortunately, I get only one value:

```
       MSE
1 14.77799
```

How can I get a tibble like that above?

Comment: As you can see below, I did not encounter this problem using your code. So, you may need to [edit] your question to include more detail. For example, what is the output of `sessionInfo()`? (In case software version differences might matter). Does this problem occur in a **fresh** R session? If not, then it's due to some code that you ran but did not include in your question. Etc.

Comment: I suspect that `summarise` is masked by another package. Try `dplyr::summarise`. As a side note, I always type out `dplyr::filter`, `dplyr::select` and `dplyr::sumarise` so that the people whose questions I answer (and I myself) don't make this mistake.

Comment: Ian Campbell: you are right, it was a problem with packages. Thank you also to duckmayr. It worked when I restarted RStudio and ran your code (and just loaded your libraries). Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @E_H Not a stupid question! It does show the importance of one particular statement in the R tag info, though: "Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls." In future questions, if you specify all non-base packages you're using with the `library()` lines, like I did in my answer, it will allow potential answerers to see what your issue is faster. Glad you got it sorted, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code, I get the style of output you are expecting (though the numbers are different (as the seed wasn't set in your example)); I do not see a summarise-type problem like you do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(modelr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
data(mpg)

cv  <- crossv_kfold(mpg, k = 5)

models1  <- map(cv$train, ~lm(hwy ~ displ, data = .))

get_pred  <- function(model, test_data){
    data  <- as.data.frame(test_data)
    pred  <- add_predictions(data, model)
    return(pred)
}

pred1  <- map2_df(models1, cv$test, get_pred, .id = "Run")

MSE1  <- pred1 %>% group_by(Run) %>% 
    summarise(MSE = mean( (hwy - pred)^2))
MSE1

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Run     MSE
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1      7.80
2 2     12.5 
3 3      9.82
4 4     27.3 
5 5     17.5
```

Comment: Your code works, thanks. My problem was, I have loaded additional libraries that have masked the summarize function.